# WooCommerce Subscriptions: Show monthly Price for annual Product

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, subscription

Using WooCommerce Subscriptions, is there a way to show a monthly price as well as a "total duration" price?

On my site I have subscriptions for a month and others for a year. Those for a year look very expensive (because the price for the whole year is shown), even though their monthly price would actually be cheaper. Would be great to show them as "€10 / months (€120 / year)".